# attach image as body in POST request to golang server

Tags: javascript, jquery, go

I have a local golang server with an endpoint that listens to POST requests, decodes the body of the request, and persists it. This works when I manually curl the endpoint like

```
    curl -X POST localhost:8080/newimage --data-binary "PATH"
```

However, I'm having trouble successfully uploading a file in a POST request through a gui I'm working on. I'm using https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone to drop a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and appending it to a FormData object, but the golang server does not seem to be receiving a populated body.

This is how I'm creating the AJAX query:

```
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", file)
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/items/81d648b0-25f9-434e-9129-fe52575865dd/newimage",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false
    }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

And the backend server:

```
func (h *ItemHandler) PostImage(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
vars := mux.Vars(req)
itemID := vars["id"]
assetID := newAssetID()

// verify image
img, _, err := image.Decode(req.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("could not decode body into an image")
    resp.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    resp.Write([]byte("could not decode body image"))
    return
}
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to `Content-Type` header which is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. Try change it to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Never done that in Go, but should you be decoding the `image` field of the request data ? The body probably doesn't contain a valid image… more something like `image=YourImageEncodingData`

Comment: You only examine if `err != nil`, but _what is_ the error? `error` is not just a `bool`-like type (being `nil` or non-`nil`)...

Answer (score 0):

FormData is very different from sending the image as raw bytes.
Here is an example on how to get the files from a multipart/form-data request:

```
func (h *ItemHandler) PostImage(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  vars := mux.Vars(req)
  itemID := vars["id"]
  assetID := newAssetID()

  file, _, err := req.FormFile("image")
  if err != nil{
    log.Print(err)
    resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
  }

  // verify image
  img, _, err := image.Decode(file)
  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("could not decode body into an image")
    resp.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    resp.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    resp.Write([]byte("could not decode body image"))
    return
  }
  ...
}
```

See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile